# Unable to install proxybroker in PIP

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, windows, pip

I am trying to install **proxybroker** using PIP on Python 3.9.1, but I am getting the the following error, when I entered **pip install proxybroker**:-

```
Collecting proxybroker
  Using cached proxybroker-0.3.2-py3-none-any.whl (1.6 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: aiohttp>=3.5.4 in c:\users\jshs\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from proxybroker) (3.7.3)
Requirement already satisfied: attrs==19.1.0 in c:\users\jshs\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from proxybroker) (19.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: maxminddb>=1.4.1 in c:\users\jshs\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from proxybroker) (2.0.3)
Collecting aiodns>=2.0.0
  Using cached aiodns-2.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (4.8 kB)
Collecting pycares>=3.0.0
  Using cached pycares-3.1.1.tar.gz (233 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: multidict<7.0,>=4.5 in c:\users\jshs\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from aiohttp>=3.5.4->proxybroker) (5.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<4.0,>=2.0 in c:\users\jshs\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from aiohttp>=3.5.4->proxybroker) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: yarl<2.0,>=1.0 in c:\users\jshs\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from aiohttp>=3.5.4->proxybroker) (1.6.3)
Requirement already satisfied: async-timeout<4.0,>=3.0 in c:\users\jshs\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from aiohttp>=3.5.4->proxybroker) (3.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions>=3.6.5 in c:\users\jshs\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from aiohttp>=3.5.4->proxybroker) (3.7.4.3)
Requirement already satisfied: cffi>=1.5.0 in c:\users\jshs\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from pycares>=3.0.0->aiodns>=2.0.0->proxybroker) (1.14.5)
Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in c:\users\jshs\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from cffi>=1.5.0->pycares>=3.0.0->aiodns>=2.0.0->proxybroker) (2.20)
Requirement already satisfied: idna>=2.0 in c:\users\jshs\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from yarl<2.0,>=1.0->aiohttp>=3.5.4->proxybroker) (2.10)
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for pycares, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: pycares, aiodns, proxybroker
    Running setup.py install for pycares ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\jshs\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\JSHS\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-kpsxgm2p\\pycares_9e37196811bb4121bae779a1fb0ccf7f\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\JSHS\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-kpsxgm2p\\pycares_9e37196811bb4121bae779a1fb0ccf7f\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\JSHS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-c7u1qn2z\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\jshs\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\Include\pycares'
         cwd: C:\Users\JSHS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-kpsxgm2p\pycares_9e37196811bb4121bae779a1fb0ccf7f\
    Complete output (26 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\pycares
    copying src\pycares\errno.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\pycares
    copying src\pycares\utils.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\pycares
    copying src\pycares\_version.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\pycares
    copying src\pycares\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\pycares
    copying src\pycares\__main__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\pycares
    running build_ext
    generating cffi module 'build\\temp.win-amd64-3.9\\Release\\_cares.c'
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release
    building '_cares' extension
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\build
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\build\temp.win-amd64-3.9
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\deps
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\deps\c-ares
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\deps\c-ares\src
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DCARES_PULL_WS2TCPIP_H=1 -Ic:\users\jshs\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include -Ic:\users\jshs\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include -Ideps\c-ares\src -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\include /Tcbuild\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\_cares.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\_cares.obj
    _cares.c
    c:\users\jshs\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include\pyconfig.h(59): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'io.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.28.29333\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\jshs\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\JSHS\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-kpsxgm2p\\pycares_9e37196811bb4121bae779a1fb0ccf7f\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\JSHS\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-kpsxgm2p\\pycares_9e37196811bb4121bae779a1fb0ccf7f\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\JSHS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-c7u1qn2z\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\jshs\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\Include\pycares' Check the logs for full command output.
```

It says that Microsoft build tools are missing, so I installed that too, but still not working!

Please help if possible!

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to downgrade the python version?
I suspect it is because of the version that you are using.

From this link, it seems that it is compatible to python 3.5 or 3.6.
https://pypi.org/project/proxybroker/

Comment: It says it requires, python 3.5 or above, so instead of python 3.9, I tried 3.8 but still, not working!

Comment: I have tried both 3.9 and 3.8 on my macintosh. The pip installation was successful in both conda created virtualenv. Just curious, are you interested in using anaconda? Maybe it is because of some missing file in your existing installed python3.9. You can create a entire fresh installation of python3.8 and 3.9 to allow pip installation of this pacakge. Hope this helps...